# Javascript onBlur - Magento Billing Email

Tags: javascript, php, magento

On the Magento Onepage Checkout I want to place an onBlur event on the billing:email input, here is my code:

```
<div class="field col-md-6">
  <div class="input-box">
    <input type="text" onblur="showme()" name="billing[email]" id="billing:email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="form-control input-text validate-email required-entry" />
  </div>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function showme() {
      alert('hello');
    }
  </script>                                                 
</div>
```

I was expecting the `showme()` function to fire but nothing happens, what have I done wrong?

Comment: works for me in test

Comment: for me too - https://jsfiddle.net/gpr965nw/

Comment: Grrrr I hate Magento sometimes! Must be something dumb happening

Comment: To be clear - I'm NOT using Magento!

Comment: mean how to work onBlur event in javascript ?